# avoiding sqlite reader starvation

Tags: c, sqlite

I have two processes with a shared sqlite database, each one has its own connection to the database. one process writes to the database in a high rate, and one process reads from the database. My concern is how to avoid "reader starvation" issue, since the writer accesses the database in a high rate, thus locking the database for the reader.

I'm using [`sqlite3_busy_timeout`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) so the reader waits if the database is locked, but from the `sqlite3_busy_timeout` description I understand that the busy handler simply sleeps a few times with retries. if the writer happnens to lock the database at those times, non of the retries will succeed.

The [`sqlite file locking documentation`](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) describes an opposite problem: "writer starvation" and the mitigations in sqlite version 3. but I couldn't find any reference to the opposite problem "reader starvation". are there any best practices to avoid such issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the database in [WAL mode](https://sqlite.org/wal.html).

> WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently.